# Constructing and object of a class and calling it's methode in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Trying to program that can read a MySql database. Somehow I cannot call the methode connect(). It says:

> Error: cannot find symbol"
>   connect.connnect();
>   _______^

What I'm trying to do is to have the connnect and getData method in different classes, so I can also use the connect class seperately for other projects.

Main:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

 public static void main( String argv[]) {

  Connect connect = new Connect();
  Connect.connect();
  GetData getdata = new GetData();
  getdata.getdata();  
 }
}
```

Connect:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect{

 public Connection con;
 public Statement st;
 public ResultSet rs;

 public connect(){
  try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/leichtathletik","root","");
     st = con.createStatement();

  }catch(Exception e1) {
   System.out.println("Error: "+e1);
  }
 }
}
```

GetData:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class GetData {

  public void getData() {

    try {
      String query = "select * läufer";
      rs = st.esecuteQuery(query);

      while (rs.next()) { 
        String vorname = rs.getString("vorname");
        String nachname = rs.getString("nachname");
        System.out.println(vorname+" "+nachname);
      } // end of while

    } catch(Exception e2) {
      System.out.println("Error: "+e2);
    }    
  }  
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: There Might be Confusion because the `java.sql.*` library has a connect object also but you're referencing you're own object. you might have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The "connect"- method on the Connect class needs to have a type.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html , can be helpful.

Further more, the youtuber (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCiczh_Q-rC7VhMV0x6__dBw) can maybe help you get started with java.